# Hive ParseException in Drop Table Statement

Tags: python, hadoop, encoding, hive, pyodbc

I'm using python and pyodbc module in particular to execute Hive queries on Hadoop. The portion of code triggering issue is like this:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas

oConnexionString = 'Driver={ClouderaHive};[...]'
oConnexion = pyodbc.connect(oConnexionString, autocommit=True)
oConnexion.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
oQueryParameter = "select * from my_db.my_table;"
oParameterData = pandas.read_sql(oQueryParameter, oConnexion)
oCursor = oConnexion.cursor()

for oRow in oParameterData.index:
    sTableName = oParameterData.loc[oRow,'TableName']
    oQueryDeleteTable = 'drop table if exists my_db.' + sTableName + ';'
    print(oQueryDeleteTable)
    oCursor.execute(oQueryDeleteTable)
```

The print gives this: `drop table if exists dl_audit_data_quality.hero_context_start_gamemode;`

But the `cursor.execute` triggers the following error message

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Cloudera][HiveODBC] (80) Syntax or
>   semantic analysis error thrown in server while execurint query. Error
>   message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED:
>   ParseException line 1:44 character ' (80) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Note that when I copy the print and execute it manually in Hue, it works well. I am guessing it has something to do with the encoding of the variable `sTableName` but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query was failing due to incorrect encoding of the variable `sTableName`. 
Printing the variable alone would display the text properly. Example with the print above:

```
>>> print(oQueryDeleteTable)
>>> 'drop table if exists dl_audit_data_quality.hero_context_start_gamemode;'
```

But printing the original data frame showed it contained characters like this:

```
>>> print(oParameterData.loc[oRow,'TableName']
>>> 'h\x00e\x00r\x00o\x00_c\x00o\x00n\x00t\x00e\x00x\x00t\x00'
```

Issue was solved by reworking on the encoding as described here: [Python Dictionary Contains Encoded Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827811/python-dictionary-contains-encoded-values)

```
import pyodbc
import pandas

oConnexionString = 'Driver={ClouderaHive};[...]'
oConnexion = pyodbc.connect(oConnexionString, autocommit=True)
oConnexion.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
oConnexion.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
oConnexion.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
oQueryParameter = "select * from my_db.my_table;"
oParameterData = pandas.read_sql(oQueryParameter, oConnexion)
oCursor = oConnexion.cursor()

for oRow in oParameterData.index:
    sTableName = oParameterData.loc[oRow,'TableName']
    oQueryDeleteTable = 'drop table if exists my_db.' + sTableName + ';'
    print(oQueryDeleteTable)
    oCursor.execute(oQueryDeleteTable)
```